# on pageload I need to bounce an image with decreasing height.I am able to bounce the image but with same height

Tags: javascript, css

I want an image to bounce with decreasing height with every bounce

I am able to bounce the image ,but not getting logic to provide decreasing height

```
  @keyframes vertically {
   60%   { 
   -moz-transform: translateY(70%); /* Browser bug fix */
   -webkit-transform: translateY(70%); /* Browser bug fix */
    transform: translateY(50%);         
     }
  100% { 
    -moz-transform: translateY(0%); /* Browser bug fix */
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0%); /* Browser bug fix */
     transform: translateY(50%); 
      }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/y51djxru/1/

Answer (score 0):

I think that an attribute which is `animation-direction` can help you.That's my code:

```
        .vertically .inner {
            //That's probably what you want
            animation-direction:alternate;
        }
```